# Use different LaserScan source for obstacle avoidance

Tags: ros, navigation, laserscan, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use different LaserScan source for obstacle avoidance? In my robot model I have several laser scanners installed and want to use one for navigation and the other one (possible more than one) for obstacle avoidance. I am using ROS Indigo and Kinetic with standard navigation stack.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235990/use-different-laserscan-source-for-obstacle-avoidance/) by [Constantine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27063/constantine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.
In the costmap configuration you can specify the observation_sources, where you can choose a different topic.
Look under the costmap configuration section here:  http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup.

---

Originally posted by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) with karma: 153 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1